# Vectorizing MANDIST (Manhattan distance) with BSXFUN - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, lambda, vectorization, bsxfun

I am trying to write a function to compute one-to-one manhattan distances of all row vectors, There is a built-in function called `mandist()` which belong to the ANN toolbox --

```
data = rand(4,2);
disp(data)
mandist(data')

>> mdtest
    0.7996    0.8884
    0.5735    0.4954
    0.9732    0.3516
    0.6341    0.7142

ans =

         0    0.6191    0.7104    0.3397
    0.6191         0    0.5435    0.2793
    0.7104    0.5435         0    0.7018
    0.3397    0.2793    0.7018         0
```

I was wondering if I could optimize the `mandist()` with `bsxfun`.
The `bsxfun` version looks like below --

```
[r,~] = size(rand);
abs(bsxfun(@minus, ...
    repmat(permute(data, [1 3 2]),1,r), ...
    repmat(permute(data, [3 1 2]),r,1)))
```

The above statement can generate all the matrices that computes `abs(a - b)` --

```
ans(:,:,1) =

         0    0.2261    0.1736    0.1656
    0.2261         0    0.3997    0.0605
    0.1736    0.3997         0    0.3392
    0.1656    0.0605    0.3392         0

ans(:,:,2) =

         0    0.3930    0.5368    0.1742
    0.3930         0    0.1438    0.2188
    0.5368    0.1438         0    0.3626
    0.1742    0.2188    0.3626         0
```

Now I want to add them all at once, is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for [`mandist.m`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/mandist.html) states the following:

> The Manhattan distance between two vectors P(:,i) and P(:,j) is
>   calculated as out(i,j) = sum(abs(data(:,i) - data(:,j))).

To create a vectorized version of `mandist`, you can use [`permute`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to create `singleton dimensions` and then let [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) cast its *magic spell* on them to get the final output -

```
out = sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,permute(data,[1 3 2]),permute(data,[3 1 2]))),3);
```

Comment: thanks again Divakar, one thing I don't quite understand, why `repmat` is not required ?

Comment: @ramgorur Well `bsxfun` does replication/expansion under the hood which is exactly what `repmat` does. So, actually you were not needed to use `repmat` there. Hope it makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `bsxfun` is faster than the `mandist` again --

```
clear all 

data = rand(500,500);
[~,col] = size(data);
maxrun = 20 ;

%warm up
for k = 1:50000
    tic(); elapsed = toc();
end

toctime = 0 ;
for i = 1:maxrun
    tic
    mandist(data');
    toctime = toctime + toc ;
end
fprintf('elapsed time: %0.4f\n', toctime/maxrun);

toctime = 0 ;
for i = 1:maxrun
    tic
    sum(abs(bsxfun(@minus,permute(data,[1 3 2]),...
                          permute(data,[3 1 2]))),3);
    toctime = toctime + toc ;
end
fprintf('elapsed time: %0.4f\n', toctime/maxrun);
```

and the result --

```
>> mdtest
elapsed time: 1.1753
elapsed time: 0.7733
```

Comment: Good to see the runtimes too!